# ¿Cómo hacer un ' input="text" ' autoactualizable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Buen día, quiero agregar esta propiedad especifica para un `input` de `HTML` que visualizará la hora del sistema, pero me gustaría que el contador de segundos y minutos estuviera actualizándose cada segundo, no se si me explico, hasta ahora solo cambia cuando actualizo la pagina por obvias razones.

Este es el código de la hora:

```
<?php 
   date_default_timezone_get();
   $time = date_default_timezone_set("America/Hermosillo");
   $time=date("h:i:s a");
?>
```

y este es el codigo de mi input:

```
<label>Hora entrada</label>
<input type="text" readonly="true" value="<?php echo($time); ?>"></input>
<br /><br />
```

**A grandes rasgos lo que busco es un contador de horas minutos y segundos dentro de un input**

Answer (score 3):

Para probar se puede poner esto en prueba_timer.html y verlo en el navegador

```
<input id=the_input>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  setInterval(function(){ 
     document.getElementById('the_input').value=(new Date()).toTimeString().substr(0,8); 
  },1000);
});
</script>
```

**Se destaca**:

1. el window.addEventListener para asegurarse que la página se termine de cargar
2. setInterval (para repetir cada 1000 milisegundos)
3. el substr (si no se quiere mostrar el timezone)

Comment: Claro que ese la hora del navegador (del lado del cliente) y no del servidor. Además hay que agregar un ID al input (<input id=the_input... )

Comment: Para hacerlo con la hora del servidor te quedan dos opciones (y sus mixtos), mandar una vez la hora del servidor (con ajax), calcular la diferencia con la hora actual y mostrar (gracias a la diferencia) siempre la hora del servidor (basándose en la del cliente). O si no enviar un ajax cada segundo y mostrar lo que el servidor devuelva.

Comment: he probado tu codigo de igual forma no actualiza cada segundo, y efectivamente parece que necesito la ayuda de ajax.

Comment: ahí adapté la solución. La anterior no funcionaba porque usé setTimeout (que corre una sola vez), el substr estaba corrido un lugar y la función toJSON devuelve la hora en la zona horaria GMT0 en vez de la zona local.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la librería [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/) con el modulo [timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) para así poder usar fechas con su correspondiente uso horario.

Código HTML

```
<label>Hora entrada</label>
<input id="reloj" type="text" readonly="true" ></input>
<br /><br />
```

Código Javascript

```
function RefrescarMostrarHora() {
    var s = moment().tz("America/Hermosillo").format('hh:mm:ss a');    
    document.getElementById("reloj").innerHTML = s;
}

RefrescarMostrarHora(); //para la priemra carga
setInterval(RefrescarMostrarHora, 500); //cada medio segundo se refresca
```

Comment: muchas gracias, pero... crees que tenga algun error el codigo, ya que me muestra el input en blanco.